# GitLab CI: Get branch name from merge-request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently looking for a way to have the Branch name in a Merge Request. I know that there is a `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` variable that returns the value of the current Branch, but this is not my case.

That is, when the Branch Master merges the changes from Branch Foo, the pipeline returns the name of that Branch, either by a builtin variable or another method. How to say, show the author of that Merge Request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can you give a complete example explaining what value you're looking for? Maybe check the [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and see if what you're looking for is there.